# DB setup for postgresql with internal and external use

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration

I am looking for input on DB Postgresql setup.

We want to move away from MS Access and move to Postgresql. We have two kinds of tables.
Tables that are used to give data out to external users and another set of tables that are used to get data back from external users. Both sets of tables are used by on-premise users.

Would it be best to have two Postgresql databases or one database with two schemas?

Comment: It depends.  Do you ever need to move data from one set to the other?  Do you ever query tables from both sets in the same query?  Why would you want to keep the tables in separate databases?

Comment: We do not want to move data between these two sets of tables. I think I want to separate them because they use different permissions. for example, one is read-only and one is write-only.

Comment: I have them in one DB and in one schema now and trying to decide if I need to move them into a different setup??

Comment: If you never share or move data across them, then it makes no difference whether you put them in separated databases or separate schemas.  That is just a preference call.